# Google Maps v3 Data Layers: Adding and removing polygon. Works first time, but not after

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 Data layers on my map: territories and newAreas.  When I draw a polygon on the map, it is saved into the newAreas data layer, processed, and then the output is added to the territories layer, and the drawn layer is removed from the map.

It all works for the first polygon I draw on the map, but subsequent drawings in the same map session don't appear to update on the map.

Here's a fiddle example.  Select the polygon in the drawing control and then draw a polygon that intersects the existing features on the map.  Then try it again.

https://jsfiddle.net/wf9g35ty/2/

I think the issue is somewhere here:

```
newAreas.addListener('addfeature', function(obj){
  //get the drawn feature in geojson format
  obj.feature.toGeoJson(function(geojson){
    //convert the existing territories data layer to geojson
    territories.toGeoJson(function(gj2){
      //merge the existing territories to a single polygon
      var features = gj2.features;
      for(i=0;i<features.length;i++) {
        if(i==0){
          var union = features[i];
        } else {
          union = turf.union(union,features[i]);
        }
      }
      //use Turf to cut out the overlapping parts
      var difference = turf.difference(geojson, union);
      //TO DO: The operation only works for the first territory added.  Figure out how to draw more than one territory in same session add the difference to the territories layer & 
      territories.addGeoJson(difference);
      // remove drawn feature.
      newAreas.remove(obj.feature);
    })
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the following two lines of code after the remove event.

```
newAreas.setMap(null);
newAreas.setMap(map);
```

I had to use setMap to basically remove the entire data layer from the map and then re-add it, which fixes the issue.  It's not very intuitive though.